# DIV overflow:auto / scroll - Inconsistent Scrollbars depending on browsers - Alternatives

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I have deliberately created a div structure whereby a scrollable div sits inside a smaller div so that the scrollbars can never be seen as over than the new transparent fading bars on OSX Lion they are hideously ugly.

```
.container {
   overflow:hidden;
   height:400px;
   width:360px;
}
.element {
   overflow:auto;
   height:400px;
   width:380px;
}
```

So thats all well and good if you have a mouse wheel, or a scroll ability on a track pad. We now need a fallback for those that don't. This could be done using jQuery but I ask a more general question.

Can the scrollbars of a div be removed and replaced with something a bit like iOS that fades in and out again over the content, showing only when scrolling is taking place.

Comment: There's a plugin here: http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll haven't used it personally. Generally consider it best practice to let browser native rendering handle scrolling even if results are sometimes different.

Comment: Annoyingly although this will respond to mouse wheel scroll it also scrolls the page. Not close enough.